# Multiple inheritance : Access Violation when executing derived function from interface

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

I have a specific problem that I can't seem to solve.    I'm building a Physics engine for an Evolution based project.   This physics structure defines an interface:

```
class IPhysicalObject
{

public:

    virtual ~IPhysicalObject(){}

    virtual PhysicalProperties*             getPhysicalProperties() = 0;
    virtual INTERSECTIONINFO*               getIntersectionInfo() = 0;
    virtual Evo::Mesh*                      getMesh() = 0;
    virtual std::vector<IPolygon*>*         getPolygons() = 0;
    virtual Evo::AABB                       getAABB() = 0;
    virtual std::string                     getType() = 0;



};
```

The rendering engine uses a structure I call `Frame`, that works like a node in a tree structure. It uses a parent-relative matrix to animate itself relative to its parent. It looks like this:

```
struct Frame
{
    Frame( );
    virtual ~Frame( );

    std::string                 _name;                  // The name of this frame / bone
    DirectX::XMFLOAT4X4         _parentRelativeMatrix;  // A matrix in space relative to the parent
    DirectX::XMFLOAT4X4         _absoluteMatrix;            // The World space matrix for this frame
    DirectX::XMFLOAT4X4 *       _parentsWorldMatrix;        // A pointer to the parents world matrix
    Frame *                     _pSibling;              // A pointer to a frame in the same level of the hierarchy
    Frame *                     _pChild;                    // A pointer to a frame in the next level of the hierarchy

    ID3D11Buffer *              _pWorldConstantBuffer;  // A pointer to the world matrix in the shader;
    Evo::Mesh *                 _pMesh;                 // A pointer to the Mesh that belongs to this frame

    bool                        _bWorldBufferActive = false; 

    Evo::AABB *                 _aabb;
    std::string                 _frameType = "Frame";

    void                        _computeAABBs();

private:
    void destroy( Frame * frame );                  // A function that helps the destructor recursively destroy the hierarchy

}; // struct Frame
```

I use both this struct and the `IPhyscalObject` interface to create a class I call `PhysicalFrame`. This is supposed to be an object that just extends the Frame structure a tiny bit with some Intersection and collision information.
It looks like this:

```
struct PhysicalFrame : public Evo::Frame, public IPhysicalObject
{
    //Evo::Frame                                _frame;
    Evo::PhysicalProperties                 _PhysProps;
    Evo::INTERSECTIONINFO                   _intersectInfo;



    PhysicalFrame(){ 

        _frameType = "PhysicalFrame";
        _PhysProps = Evo::PhysicalProperties();
        _intersectInfo = Evo::INTERSECTIONINFO();
    }

    virtual ~PhysicalFrame(){}

    virtual Evo::PhysicalProperties*        getPhysicalProperties() override { return &_PhysProps;  }
    virtual Evo::INTERSECTIONINFO*          getIntersectionInfo() override { return &_intersectInfo;  }
    virtual Mesh*                           getMesh() override { return _pMesh; }
    virtual std::vector<Evo::IPolygon*>*    getPolygons()override { return   _pMesh->getPolys();  }
    virtual Evo::AABB                       getAABB() override { if (_aabb) return *_aabb; _aabb = new AABB(); return *_aabb; }
    virtual std::string                     getType() { return _frameType; }

}; //---------------------------------~###~----------------------------------//
```

However.

Later in a tight routine where I fetch a pointer to a valid object of type `PhysicalFrame` and save it in a pointer of type `IPhysicalObject`, then try to invoke a function declared by the `IphysicalObject` interface, I get an Access Violation Executing at 0x00000000.

```
obj1 = dynamic_cast<IPhysicalObject*>(m_pObjects->at(i0));
if (!obj1) continue;
Evo::PhysicalProperties* prop = obj1->getPhysicalProperties();
```

The object looks valid when I break and inspect, except one member in the __vfptr list is null.

I have ABSOLUTELY emptied my mind of experiments to run.

Is there something obvious I am overlooking or is it maybe something to do with the memory layout of the structures?

Comment: Something may be wrong with the copy constructor for the type `Evo::PhysicalProperties`. Likely it's performing a shallow copy. Or, something is wrong with the type of whatever is in `m_pObjects`. Please provide a [mcve] and we can help more.

Comment: @Ceros it should work.

Comment: @George yes right. Deleted my comment

Comment: `_PhysProps` is an identifier that is reserved to the implementation because it begins with underscore and uppercase character. You should come up with another variable name.

Comment: How about the life time of the `PhysicalFrame`, when it is created and when is destructed?

Comment: if this is a new graphics engine, it probably should not contain any raw pointers at all. If these raw pointers are non-owning, they should at least be an observer_ptr. If you're checking for null, something's not right in the design. see the `lock` method of `std::weak_ptr`. (I appreciate that if this engine is single-threaded, shared_ptr/weak_ptr might be overkill.)

Comment: Both  user2079303 and Richard Hodges have good points.  the _memberName is a convention i use only for structures and sometimes it happens fast. What convention would you suggest I follow?     @Richard Hodges: It is still singlethreaded, but I already very sparsely started to implement support for multithreading, so you are right, I should start using more managed pointers.

Comment: @AndyG - I will try to provide an example, but it's hard since this is already a really early test!

Comment: @Silverback my convention is to not use hungarian notation at all, so the member would be `member_name`. I program with a syntax highlighting editor (who doesn't these days?), and I recognize members at a glance based on the colour that the editor has assigned to them. If I were forced to use hungarian notation, then I would recommend `m_` prefix, since that contains a hint of what the prefix means (m for member), and it won't be a reserved identifier.

Comment: @ user2079303 thanks! I'll definately consider that! I originally stuck with it because I moved around a lot in workplaces, and used many different editors with different color schemes. So back then it was easier for me to read.

Comment: In the meantime I tried reproducing the error on a playground project. Suddenly - when i loaded the project back up, the error had somehow resolved itself. It irritates me greatly since I feel like I wasted time and no wiser whatsoever.